# C++ Windows Plugins - Passing Classes

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, plugins

I am working on a plugin system in C++ whereby a C++ executable loads a dll and runs plugin_start(someclass&) via GetProcAddress.

I fully understand how to pass function pointers to the **dll**, and visa versa, and how the dll may use anything defined in a header file, but I would like the dll to be able to use someclass where someclass is declared in someclass.h BUT DEFINED in someclass.cpp.

The catch is, someclass is compiled into the calling **executable**  which means when the dll tries to call a function it gets a linker error.  I even understand why this is, what I don't understand is how to achieve what I want.

I imagine I can pass a pointer to the object, and a pointer to the function ie someclass* somefunction* and then call it as someclass->*somefunction() but this means I would have to pass a pointer to every function in every class.

Is there an easier way to do this, or should I stick to C-style functions and function pointers alone and forget trying to pass entire classes between the two?

Thanks,
Ben

```
#ifndef EVENTREGISTRAR_H
#define EVENTREGISTRAR_H
#include <vector>

typedef void (__stdcall *error_callback_t)(const char *error);

class EventRegistrar
{

public:
    void OnError(error_callback_t fn);
    void FireError(const char *error);


private:
    std::vector<error_callback_t> errors;

};
#endif
```

-- Cpp

```
#include "PluginLoader.h"
void EventRegistrar::OnError(error_callback_t fn)
{
    this->errors.push_back(fn);
}

void EventRegistrar::FireError(const char *error)
{
    for (std::vector<error_callback_t>::iterator it = this->errors.begin();
        it != this->errors.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)(error);
    }
}
```

-- DLL

```
#include "../plugin.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void __stdcall error(const char *error) { printf("Error: %s\n",error); }
extern "C" int __stdcall plugin_start(plugin_start_data& data)
{
    error_callback_t fn = error;
    data.events.OnError(fn);
    return LOAD_SUCCESS;
}
```

--Error

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall EventRegistrar::OnError(void (__stdcall*)(char const *))" (?OnError@EventRegistrar@@QAEXP6GXPBD@Z@Z) D:\Files\C++ Workspace\BLib\BLib\Example Plugin\main.obj    Example Plugin
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to pass STL objects across DLL boundaries; separate the interface from the implementation so you can avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this a long time ago. I simply used a straight C interface to keep things simple.

There may be a better way but I think passing a pointer to the object is your best and most straight-forward approach.

Comment: I'd still have to also pass a pointer to the functions, correct? I tried just passing a pointer to the object, data->events->OnError(fn); and still have a linker error.

Comment: No, if the header file is available at compile time, you should only need to pass a pointer to the object. I'm not 100% clear on what you are doing with those events. Certainly, that would complicate things. But referencing a class member from a pointer should not involve any linker errors. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Quite confused. Making the members of EventRegistrar virtual makes my problem disappear and everything work dandy.

Comment: I can't say why without spending more time on your code. But if you just pass the pointer, there is no compile-time linkage going on. That's why I said a linker error doesn't make sense to me. At any rate, if it's working then perhaps you've found a satisfactory solution.